# I need change code from vega-lite to Vega

Tags: vega, mindsphere

please i need help with code port for graph from Vega-lite to Vega - I created graph in Vega-lite, code and img see below, in Vega editor it works fine for me, but Minsphere (I think) supports only Vega. I'm trying it with "export" => JSON => compiled Vega. But it not work for me. Can anyone help me. Thank you ;-)

[image :-)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YWzo.jpg)

````
    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Machine",
  "width":"container",
  "height":30,
  "config": {
    "legend": {"orient": "bottom", "layout": {"bottom": {"anchor": "middle"}},"title": null}
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
        {"time": "2022-01-27T05:00:43.674Z", "y":1 , "stav":"produkce"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T07:32:13.671Z", "y": 0, "stav":"produkce"},
                
        {"time": "2022-01-27T07:32:13.671Z", "y": 1, "stav":"error"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:32:13.671Z", "y": 0, "stav":"error"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:52:13.671Z", "y": 1, "stav":"error"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T10:41:13.671Z", "y": 0, "stav":"error"},

        {"time": "2022-01-27T08:32:13.671Z", "kusy": 1},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T08:32:14.671Z", "kusy": 0},

        {"time": "2022-01-27T08:42:13.671Z", "program": 1},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T08:42:14.671Z", "program": 0},

        {"time": "2022-01-27T06:42:13.671Z", "program": 1},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T06:42:14.671Z", "program": 0},

        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:42:13.671Z", "program": 1},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:42:14.671Z", "program": 0},

        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:32:13.671Z", "y": 1, "stav":"nastaveni"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:52:13.671Z", "y": 0, "stav":"nastaveni"},
        
        {"time": "2022-01-27T05:05:43.674Z", "prestavka": 1.2, "od":1}, 
        {"time": "2022-01-27T06:05:43.674Z", "prestavka": 0, "od":0}       
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"title":false,
    "timeUnit":"hoursminutes",
    "field": "time",
    "type":"temporal", 
    "axis": {"format": "%H:%M","tickCount": 4}
    
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
    "mark": {"type": "area","interpolate": "step-after", "tooltip":true},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "y", 
          "type": "quantitative", "stack":false, 
          "axis": {"title":null, "labels":false, "ticks": false}},
          "color": {
            "field":"stav", 
            "type":"nominal",
            "scale":{
              "domain":["produkce","error","nastaveni","kusy","prestavka","program"],
              "range":["green","red","yellow","black", "grey","blue"]
            }
          },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field":"stav"},
          {"field": "time", "type": "temporal","format": "%d.%m.%y - %H:%M"}
        ]
      }
    },
    {
    "mark": {"type": "area", "color": "grey", "interpolate": "step-after","tooltip":true},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "prestavka", 
          "type": "quantitative", 
          "stack":false, 
          "axis": {"title":null, "labels":false, "ticks": false}
        },
        "y2":{
          "field":"od",
          "type": "quantitative"          
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field":"prestavka"},
          {"field": "time", "type": "temporal","format": "%d.%m.%y - %H:%M"}
        ]
      }
    },
    {
    "mark": {"type": "line","point": {"filled":true, "fill":"black"},"line":false, "tooltip":true},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "kusy",
          "type": "quantitative", "stack":false, 
          "axis": {"title":null, "labels":false, "ticks": false}
        },
          "tooltip": [
            {"field":"kusy"},
            {"field": "time", "type": "temporal","format": "%d.%m.%y - %H:%M"}
            ]
      }
    },
    {
    "mark": {"type": "line","point": {"filled":true, "fill":"blue"},"line":false, "tooltip":true},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "program",
          "type": "quantitative", "stack":false, 
          "axis": {"title":null, "labels":false, "ticks": false}
        },
          "tooltip": [
            {"field":"program"},
            {"field": "time", "type": "temporal","format": "%d.%m.%y - %H:%M"}
            ]
      }
    }
  ]
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the Vega-Lite spec to the [Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AFkksGrLiKQAdxrL6aEFDmYkJuOvPwaZLGgDMABiUHWQAzTzRQQXI4WWVwkDZNaMw7JjZsNgRzQSQATzYGZNRQVPTMopAkWVgEuwRrZUiQAF8mpR1MRtRZBkFBFqVlJCc44iRBBjU0AG1QHQQzdAAmP0XF-j8ARn5FgHYAFT8xVD8-VAAWH0oANh2zgC1zHLQNpQgnYjscdTZlBgBrKBmVqzGjzOzLVbrLa7A47VA+RaoDaXG4bB5KJ7HV7vT7fX4AoEKEFgpYrNabbb7PxwhFIlE7NGPZ7YpAfdCub5uYEgOYLEAQ8nQqkATnhiOR1wZ6JAmICIDerLsHJq3N54LJUMpB1FYnF9MZGOZ8px7PUnOaRJ5oL5As1MI2pzOGzpkoNMrQcoVbJAyq5lrVpMhFJhfgAHGKXajpX8GBBMRtVdb1UGhQdw7SNmdXdHY7LEyT+Rrg1Tw2c9dnzF82GR1Egygn-UnA4KtWHzuKs1HK98a3WPfmbUXU34ru3I1Lu9Xa-WB8mWyHR2WkZ2J0oq72yn5Z827SKxxKu2ue9PntvCynW6Kl5mK0ep33jmfbcXtRGD6v3UiWd7ZEgvdEaAtYlBwvEMdXLQ9P09E0QF-f9ZEAp8h1bI5DnOel7m7NR3j+FAkUoRYlB+U9GwLZ9h1HNCLklTCj2w1lcI9IjYkfABdVofSqH4TDIOIAA84naTpgjGCA4Daa0AFUEMKDB8nUCA6m6TBJiUUI4EEFirTBNochwPkVIQHAEjGcwkD4mgIDiYIEmQWSAFIAAlUHs-RzB0KA-gAYXyWRCjOFoOOyHJXGmUBkHUP5BL0vkkHUOAUCUEwVPUYzshUuw3jgHB+CQYIUvctg2EEHQcDQTB1AmDjogcZQeLiTFQHUzS7CeXT9LsABHBhKnaIYaFIcwFU8tARMEMSlHMyzBLoTpul6JRsiYDSrNQMaJqtTzVvWuB+nsYqanKZqtK9dyYrsWQMhMUzXigMYFlAZQMmcPQphAKt8UBcxfXMOD3gA8wYzjLCvUYu8NxAVilFrWQyAWN6azgaJzHi2IMQ0wQ2AscwmGyEalERtqQFxiZIb2zAipKrQwpAY7Mpxbk6fQNV2oMxBjNrQRzBs9Q7LsezlEoeyECFnIAAJ+DFpyXLcpp2O5CKovKTBzvQOKEvMBxMbcdBCfMZLXDSoY+SynK8oKtpKdK8rKt2pQau42GGusmgNK0r56OIMGeVVkBut6uh+sGlkRrW0TxIqCzVpBDoFnmwRFqQZbxtG8OJK21Pxt2jickWF23bsYjWa6nq-MDnRBo4iniut1AZlp12WvQD3QZQRnG60lmfY65n2ZMrm1NsoZ+cF4XRYlqXnNc5p5ctRXop7kBhFMSs2GSl3ejgFiKomNSaF6FI8aioKXEzjbq6psrUB3u3ONq+rykahuC-QIGiZVxf-bLpwK7MEOlZ2pNKOM1Y5oHjonZO2006bT+FArO5MrbUzrk1Dudg35AWfk3bSf9u5syMv3bmQ8HKjxFvZcWktpbTzlv0cKcUlazF9svHBxl15HX3pEbets94H3QCTQkS9T5hyzpbGuSCb7VS4nVJ2j985YPXCeYu6Av59V-kNJwodAGR2msrWaccegJyXknFaZ8I4eVgSYhBoir71yZu9Y8fZ24v2wWdRehkOY3VpkQkeQtSHkMnjLGeLR2JAA) and it will show the compiled Vega spec

[image]

Compiled Vega spec:

```
{
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
"description": "Machine",
"autosize": {"type": "fit-x", "contains": "padding"},
"background": "white",
"padding": 5,
"height": 30,
"style": "cell",
"data": [
    {
    "name": "source_0",
    "values": [
        {"time": "2022-01-27T05:00:43.674Z", "y": 1, "stav": "produkce"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T07:32:13.671Z", "y": 0, "stav": "produkce"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T07:32:13.671Z", "y": 1, "stav": "error"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:32:13.671Z", "y": 0, "stav": "error"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:52:13.671Z", "y": 1, "stav": "error"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T10:41:13.671Z", "y": 0, "stav": "error"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T08:32:13.671Z", "kusy": 1},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T08:32:14.671Z", "kusy": 0},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T08:42:13.671Z", "program": 1},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T08:42:14.671Z", "program": 0},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T06:42:13.671Z", "program": 1},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T06:42:14.671Z", "program": 0},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:42:13.671Z", "program": 1},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:42:14.671Z", "program": 0},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:32:13.671Z", "y": 1, "stav": "nastaveni"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T09:52:13.671Z", "y": 0, "stav": "nastaveni"},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T05:05:43.674Z", "prestavka": 1.2, "od": 1},
        {"time": "2022-01-27T06:05:43.674Z", "prestavka": 0, "od": 0}
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "data_0",
    "source": "source_0",
    "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "toDate(datum[\"time\"])", "as": "time"},
        {
        "field": "time",
        "type": "timeunit",
        "units": ["hours", "minutes"],
        "as": ["hoursminutes_time", "hoursminutes_time_end"]
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "data_2",
    "source": "data_0",
    "transform": [
        {
        "type": "filter",
        "expr": "(isDate(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) || (isValid(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]))) && isValid(datum[\"program\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"program\"])"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "data_3",
    "source": "data_0",
    "transform": [
        {
        "type": "filter",
        "expr": "(isDate(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) || (isValid(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]))) && isValid(datum[\"kusy\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"kusy\"])"
        }
    ]
    }
],
"signals": [
    {
    "name": "width",
    "init": "isFinite(containerSize()[0]) ? containerSize()[0] : 200",
    "on": [
        {
        "update": "isFinite(containerSize()[0]) ? containerSize()[0] : 200",
        "events": "window:resize"
        }
    ]
    }
],
"marks": [
    {
    "name": "layer_0_pathgroup",
    "type": "group",
    "from": {
        "facet": {
        "name": "faceted_path_layer_0_main",
        "data": "data_0",
        "groupby": ["stav"]
        }
    },
    "encode": {
        "update": {
        "width": {"field": {"group": "width"}},
        "height": {"field": {"group": "height"}}
        }
    },
    "marks": [
        {
        "name": "layer_0_marks",
        "type": "area",
        "style": ["area"],
        "sort": {"field": "datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]"},
        "from": {"data": "faceted_path_layer_0_main"},
        "encode": {
            "update": {
            "interpolate": {"value": "step-after"},
            "orient": {"value": "vertical"},
            "tooltip": {
                "signal": "{\"stav\": isValid(datum[\"stav\"]) ? datum[\"stav\"] : \"\"+datum[\"stav\"], \"time\": timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M')}"
            },
            "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "stav"},
            "description": {
                "signal": "\"time (hours-minutes): \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"], '%H:%M')) + \"; y: \" + (format(datum[\"y\"], \"\")) + \"; stav: \" + (isValid(datum[\"stav\"]) ? datum[\"stav\"] : \"\"+datum[\"stav\"]) + \"; time: \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M'))"
            },
            "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "hoursminutes_time"},
            "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y"},
            "y2": {"scale": "y", "value": 0},
            "defined": {
                "signal": "isValid(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) && isValid(datum[\"y\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"y\"])"
            }
            }
        }
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "layer_1_marks",
    "type": "area",
    "style": ["area"],
    "sort": {"field": "datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]"},
    "from": {"data": "data_0"},
    "encode": {
        "update": {
        "interpolate": {"value": "step-after"},
        "orient": {"value": "vertical"},
        "tooltip": {
            "signal": "{\"prestavka\": isValid(datum[\"prestavka\"]) ? datum[\"prestavka\"] : \"\"+datum[\"prestavka\"], \"time\": timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M')}"
        },
        "fill": {"value": "grey"},
        "description": {
            "signal": "\"time (hours-minutes): \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"], '%H:%M')) + \"; prestavka: \" + (format(datum[\"prestavka\"], \"\")) + \"; od: \" + (format(datum[\"od\"], \"\")) + \"; time: \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M'))"
        },
        "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "hoursminutes_time"},
        "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "prestavka"},
        "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "od"},
        "defined": {
            "signal": "isValid(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) && isValid(datum[\"prestavka\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"prestavka\"])"
        }
        }
    }
    },
    {
    "name": "layer_2_layer_0_marks",
    "type": "line",
    "style": ["line"],
    "sort": {"field": "datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]"},
    "from": {"data": "data_0"},
    "encode": {
        "update": {
        "tooltip": {
            "signal": "{\"kusy\": isValid(datum[\"kusy\"]) ? datum[\"kusy\"] : \"\"+datum[\"kusy\"], \"time\": timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M')}"
        },
        "stroke": {"value": "#4c78a8"},
        "description": {
            "signal": "\"time (hours-minutes): \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"], '%H:%M')) + \"; kusy: \" + (format(datum[\"kusy\"], \"\")) + \"; time: \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M'))"
        },
        "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "hoursminutes_time"},
        "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "kusy"},
        "defined": {
            "signal": "isValid(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) && isValid(datum[\"kusy\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"kusy\"])"
        }
        }
    }
    },
    {
    "name": "layer_2_layer_1_marks",
    "type": "symbol",
    "style": ["point"],
    "from": {"data": "data_3"},
    "encode": {
        "update": {
        "opacity": {"value": 1},
        "fill": {"value": "black"},
        "tooltip": {
            "signal": "{\"kusy\": isValid(datum[\"kusy\"]) ? datum[\"kusy\"] : \"\"+datum[\"kusy\"], \"time\": timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M')}"
        },
        "ariaRoleDescription": {"value": "point"},
        "description": {
            "signal": "\"time (hours-minutes): \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"], '%H:%M')) + \"; kusy: \" + (format(datum[\"kusy\"], \"\")) + \"; time: \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M'))"
        },
        "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "hoursminutes_time"},
        "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "kusy"}
        }
    }
    },
    {
    "name": "layer_3_layer_0_marks",
    "type": "line",
    "style": ["line"],
    "sort": {"field": "datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]"},
    "from": {"data": "data_0"},
    "encode": {
        "update": {
        "tooltip": {
            "signal": "{\"program\": isValid(datum[\"program\"]) ? datum[\"program\"] : \"\"+datum[\"program\"], \"time\": timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M')}"
        },
        "stroke": {"value": "#4c78a8"},
        "description": {
            "signal": "\"time (hours-minutes): \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"], '%H:%M')) + \"; program: \" + (format(datum[\"program\"], \"\")) + \"; time: \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M'))"
        },
        "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "hoursminutes_time"},
        "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "program"},
        "defined": {
            "signal": "isValid(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"]) && isValid(datum[\"program\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"program\"])"
        }
        }
    }
    },
    {
    "name": "layer_3_layer_1_marks",
    "type": "symbol",
    "style": ["point"],
    "from": {"data": "data_2"},
    "encode": {
        "update": {
        "opacity": {"value": 1},
        "fill": {"value": "blue"},
        "tooltip": {
            "signal": "{\"program\": isValid(datum[\"program\"]) ? datum[\"program\"] : \"\"+datum[\"program\"], \"time\": timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M')}"
        },
        "ariaRoleDescription": {"value": "point"},
        "description": {
            "signal": "\"time (hours-minutes): \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"hoursminutes_time\"], '%H:%M')) + \"; program: \" + (format(datum[\"program\"], \"\")) + \"; time: \" + (timeFormat(datum[\"time\"], '%d.%m.%y - %H:%M'))"
        },
        "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "hoursminutes_time"},
        "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "program"}
        }
    }
    }
],
"scales": [
    {
    "name": "x",
    "type": "time",
    "domain": {
        "fields": [
        {"data": "data_0", "field": "hoursminutes_time"},
        {"data": "data_3", "field": "hoursminutes_time"},
        {"data": "data_2", "field": "hoursminutes_time"}
        ]
    },
    "range": [0, {"signal": "width"}]
    },
    {
    "name": "y",
    "type": "linear",
    "domain": {
        "fields": [
        {"data": "data_0", "field": "y"},
        {"data": "data_0", "field": "prestavka"},
        {"data": "data_0", "field": "od"},
        {"data": "data_0", "field": "kusy"},
        {"data": "data_3", "field": "kusy"},
        {"data": "data_0", "field": "program"},
        {"data": "data_2", "field": "program"}
        ]
    },
    "range": [{"signal": "height"}, 0],
    "nice": true,
    "zero": true
    },
    {
    "name": "color",
    "type": "ordinal",
    "domain": [
        "produkce",
        "error",
        "nastaveni",
        "kusy",
        "prestavka",
        "program"
    ],
    "range": ["green", "red", "yellow", "black", "grey", "blue"]
    }
],
"axes": [
    {
    "scale": "x",
    "orient": "bottom",
    "tickCount": 4,
    "gridScale": "y",
    "grid": true,
    "domain": false,
    "labels": false,
    "aria": false,
    "maxExtent": 0,
    "minExtent": 0,
    "ticks": false,
    "zindex": 0
    },
    {
    "scale": "y",
    "orient": "left",
    "gridScale": "x",
    "grid": true,
    "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(height/40)"},
    "domain": false,
    "labels": false,
    "aria": false,
    "maxExtent": 0,
    "minExtent": 0,
    "ticks": false,
    "zindex": 0
    },
    {
    "scale": "x",
    "orient": "bottom",
    "grid": false,
    "format": "%H:%M",
    "tickCount": 4,
    "labelFlush": true,
    "labelOverlap": true,
    "zindex": 0
    },
    {
    "scale": "y",
    "orient": "left",
    "grid": false,
    "labels": false,
    "ticks": false,
    "labelOverlap": true,
    "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(height/40)"},
    "zindex": 0
    }
],
"legends": [
    {"fill": "color", "direction": "horizontal", "symbolType": "circle"}
],
"config": {
    "legend": {
    "orient": "bottom",
    "layout": {"bottom": {"anchor": "middle"}},
    "title": null
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Cool, I never knew you could do this.